# How do I separate by loose parts and keep the individual material?

Tags: materials

[image]

I can get all these instances separated into individual meshes using *Separate By Loose Parts* after I applied the *Geometry Node* modifier.

When I do, they all have the same material. Is there any way for each new mesh to retain its material?

Answer (score 1):

First note: *Random Per Island* is recognized only by Cycles, and seems to return the same value for the first mesh-island found in each object.

Depending on how you want to use these objects later, one option would be to store an attribute on each GN instance, that will persist after the GN modifier is applied. Here, that attribute is a random 0-1 float, for generality, but could be anything you liked:

[image]

That attribute will persist on the object's meshes, once the GN modifier is applied, and the mesh has been separated by parts. It can be picked up by your material:

[image]